# Trying to return data from a .SqlQuery just returns nulls

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to run a SQL Query against a database:

```
public partial class Report2
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }

}
var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<Report2>("Select Substring([English],1,1), Count(1) From Phrase Group by Substring([English], 1, 1)");
```

Running the select manually gives me 36 rows with values in two columns just like I would expect.

However when I run the EF version it gives me 36 objects but col1 and col2 are null in all of them.

Does anyone have any ideas why the results in Report2 would just be all nulls?

Comment: can you please try to modify your query to `Select Substring([English],1,1) Col1, Count(1) Col2....`?

Comment: you select a column named Substring and Count (most likely) from your database and map it to an object of col1 and col2. since no entries are in col1 and col2 for each row, null is returned. try SELECT Substring([English],1,1) as Col1, Count(1) as Col2 From Phrase... and set col2 to an Integer.

Comment: I think that helped but now I get a message saying: exceptionMessage=The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues in your code:

- first, you need to **name your columns** to map them to your model names:

```sql
Select Substring([English],1,1) AS Col1, Count(1) AS Col2 From Phrase Group by Substring([English], 1, 1)
```

- second, your second field **needs to be an int and not a string** (as `count` returns an integer), that's why you get an error message like `'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid`

```cs
public partial class Report2
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public int Col2 { get; set; }
}
```